# Keep directory structure in Copy Files Build Phase in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode11

In XCode 11.7, when I add a Copy Files build phase, it only allows me to select files, not directories, and while I can select files from within sub-directories, they all get mashed together into the top-level.

I can work around it by adding multiple Copy Files phases with a different subpath so that the structure ends up correct, but this is tedious and feels wrong.

Is there a better way to make the output directory structure of Copy Files match the input?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it - instead of a Copy Files phase, I added a Run Script phase and used the `cp -R` command.

In my case, I wanted to copy a `TargetApp/www` folder to the "Wrapper" (root of the app), so my full script is:

```sh
echo "copying $SRCROOT/TargetApp/www to $TARGET_BUILD_DIR/$CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH"
cp -R "$SRCROOT/TargetApp/www" "$TARGET_BUILD_DIR/$CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH"
```

Comment: This actually is the wrong answer. The correct procedure is to use a _folder reference_. When you do that, the entire folder is what is copied, lock stock and barrel, including the entire folder-and-file hierarchy that it contains, intact. I provide fairly detailed instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48758433/341994

Comment: I wasn't able to use a folder reference to copy headers from a static library since it contained C files but Run Script did the trick.