# Swift: Unable to load local images in WKWebView

Tags: swift

I am attempting to load local images from my local Bundle into my WkWebView but have not been successful.

This is my `index.html`:

```
<div>
    <img src='./images/test.png'>
    <p>Test Para</p>
</div>
```

My folder structure:

```
- web
  -- images
      -- test.png
  -- index.html
- ViewController
```

Code in ViewController that loads the HTML

Attempt 1:

```
let htmlPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "index", ofType: "html")
let htmlUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: htmlPath!, isDirectory: true)
webView.loadFileURL(htmlUrl, allowingReadAccessTo: htmlUrl)
```

Attempt 2:

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "index", withExtension: "html")!
webView.loadFileURL(url, allowingReadAccessTo: url)
```

Attempt 3:

```
let htmlPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "index", ofType: "HTML")
let folderPath = Bundle.main.bundlePath
let baseUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: folderPath, isDirectory: true)
do {
    let htmlString = try NSString(contentsOfFile: htmlPath!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
    webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString as String, baseURL: baseUrl)
} catch {
    // catch error
}
```

The solutions attempted above were suggested from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39459878/6792327) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49637828/6792327). All the above returns the following result:
[image]

Comment: Try changing `img src='./images/test.png` to `img src='test.png'`. Does it work now? If so, I can tell you what the problem is.

Comment: @matt Yes it worked. Attempt 2 and 3 works. What's the problem?

Comment: Explained it in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that this statement is wrong:

> My folder structure:
>
> ```
> - web
>   -- images
>      -- test.png
>   -- index.html
> ```

That may be what the Project navigator looks like, but those yellow things in the Project navigator ("web", "images") are *not folders*. They are just organizational devices for the Project navigator itself (*groups*), to help you find your stuff. In the built app, your resources are being loaded *flat* into the app bundle, so that *test.png* and *index.html* are at the same level together, namely, the top level of the bundle.

If what you really wanted was in fact a "web" folder with that structure inside your app bundle, then you needed this to be a *folder reference*, which is a very different thing.

Comment: See for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/48758433/341994. Your code will need to change considerably if you make a folder reference, because _index.html_ will not be at the top level any more either.